# node setInterval() multiplies outcome

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

```
setInterval(myFunction, 5000);

function myFunction(){
   console.log("hello");
}
```

So I thought this code would print "hello" every fifth second. But it doesn't. Instead, it prints whenever(roughly every fifth second). But the console message multiplies. one time it might print "hello" once, the next time twice and the time after that three times. Can someone explain to me why it is behaving like this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the complete code, there is nothing wrong in this partial code and it would print "hello" every fifth second.

Comment: your code is working perfectly

Comment: You probably call *setInterval* within *myFunction*, this creates more and more callbacks. Please show your complete code.

Comment: Hmmm I just noticed that the code i posted worked. But I'm just not console logging in myFucntion. Kinda hard to explain what I'm trying to do but it has to do with posting woocommerce products. Gonna take another look at it. probbaly not the "setinterval" that screws up then.

Comment: You have a typo in the setInterval function name